# How to remove tuples from a list of tuples?

Tags: python, tuples, playing-cards

I have a deck of cards, and I take a hand. Appalled by what I see, I want to discard the aforementioned cards and take a new hand. How do I go about this?

Basically, I can't seem to discard the tuples. I can't `deck.remove(hand)` them, and I can't seem to find another way to get rid of them. Any suggestions? My code is below. (I've seen better ways to do the cards, but I'm not good enough at Python yet to use classes. I just seek a way to remove any tuples in my hand from the deck.)

```
import random
import itertools

suits = (" of Hearts", " of Spades", " of Clubs", " of Diamonds")
ranks = ("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace")

deck = tuple("".join(card) for card in itertools.product(ranks, suits))

hand = random.sample(deck, 5)

print(hand)

for card in deck:
    if card in hand:
        # This is what I'm struggling to fill
```

Comment: Have you tried [lists] instead of (tuples,)?

Comment: Better to have a separate array `availability` and set the corresponding values to `True / False`.

Comment: tuples are immutable, so convert to list or dict for that.

Comment: Use a set for the deck

Comment: If you want to remove things from `deck`, don't use an immutable container like `tuple` to hold the cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change deck because it's tuple, but you could recreate it and leave things out. Here's what I mean:

```
import random
import itertools

suits = (" of Hearts", " of Spades", " of Clubs", " of Diamonds")
ranks = ("2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace")

deck = tuple("".join(card) for card in itertools.product(ranks, suits))

hand = random.sample(deck, 5)

# Removed hand from deck.
deck = tuple(card for card in deck if card not in set(hand))
```

You could do something similar to add items to it. If this is going to occur frequently, it would probably be better to use a mutable container, like a `list` or `dict` that would allow you do modify their contents without recreating the whole thing.

Comment: This is great, thank you! Is there a way to restrict it to removing one of each? So, for example, if I have four decks shuffled together and a Queen of Hearts in my hand, only one Queen of Hearts will be removed and not all four?

Comment: My answer assumes cards are unique as would be the case with one deck, which is what deck is in your  question. To handle multiple decks I would suggest using a `dict` instead, either a `collections.Counter` or `defaultdict` both of which are dictionary subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Use set operations. Simple solution

```
deck = tuple(set(deck) - set(tuple(hand))) # removes all the tuples from deck which are there in hand
```

Comment: Python sets ftw.